# Automatically grant runtime permissions when app installed by Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-permissions

How can I skip the permission consent dialog when an app is installed and run by Android Studio?

That is, how can I avoid the screen below when tapping ^R or clicking on "Run"?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add the `-g` flag to the "install flags" of the "Run" configuration:

1. Go to Run > Run… > Edit Configurations…
2. Add `-g` to the "Install Flags" field.

[image]

(See `adb shell pm help` for other options.)